# how would i handle argparse for single or multiple strings?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, argparse

I am using argparse to check if my input is a single timestamp string or multiple comma separated timestamp strings.

For example the input can be either `"xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx" or "xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx,xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx,xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx,,,,"`

Im passing:

```
parser.add_argument("-timestamp", dest="timestamp",required = True, help = "single or multiple timestamp of the format:xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx, seperated by ',' ", type = is_valid_string(parser, arg))
```

The following is what I had in mind, but completely lost on how to determine if its a single string or multiple string of the certain regex type (xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx)

```
def is_valid_string(parser,arg):
    if not isinstance(arg,str):
        parser.error("\n input should be of type(str)")
```

EDIT:

The following solve my problem:

```
 group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
 group.add_argument("-t", dest="timestamp", help = "timestamp should be of the format:xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx", type = lambda x: check_timestamp(parser,x))
 group.add_argument("-T", dest="timestamps", help = "timestamps should be ',' seperated and of the format:xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx", type = lambda x: is_valid_time_list(parser,x))


def is_valid_string(arg):
    if not isinstance(arg,str):
        raise TypeError("\n input should be of type(str)")

def check_valid_time(parser,arg):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(arg,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        print (1)
    except ValueError:
        print (2)
        parser.error("timestamp %s is not of valid time format"%(arg))
        return ValueError

def check_timestamp(parser,arg):
    is_valid_string(arg)
    check_valid_time(parser,arg)
    return arg

def is_valid_time_list(parser,arg):
    is_valid_string(arg)
    try:
        time_list = arg.split(',')
        for i in range(len(time_list)):
            print (str(time_list[i]))
            check_valid_time(parser,str(time_list[i]))
    except:
        parser.error("list is invalid input format!")
    return arg
```

For the Following input format:

```
python prog.py -T "2017-12-23 12:00:00.000,2017-12-23 12:00:000"
```

Comment: Split it by comma and count the number of fragments with `len`.

Comment: Review the specifications for the `type` function.  It should take one argument, a string.  It should return some object, possibly the input string itself.  Or it should raise an error.  `TypeError`, `ValueError` or `argparse.ArgumentTypeError('your message')`.

Comment: For a start it may be simpler to simply accept the string (no `type` parameter), and do your own error testing afterwards.  In other words, any conversion/testing that you can do with the `type` parameter, you can also do after parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using add_mutuall_exclusive_group along with custom error handlers the way to go!

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
 group.add_argument("-t", dest="timestamp", help = "timestamp should be of the format:xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx", type = lambda x: check_timestamp(parser,x))
 group.add_argument("-T", dest="timestamps", help = "timestamps should be ',' seperated and of the format:xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx.xxx", type = lambda x: is_valid_time_list(parser,x))


def is_valid_string(arg):
    if not isinstance(arg,str):
        raise TypeError("\n input should be of type(str)")

def check_valid_time(parser,arg):
    try:
        datetime.strptime(arg,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        print (1)
    except ValueError:
        print (2)
        parser.error("timestamp %s is not of valid time format"%(arg))
        return ValueError

def check_timestamp(parser,arg):
    is_valid_string(arg)
    check_valid_time(parser,arg)
    return arg

def is_valid_time_list(parser,arg):
    is_valid_string(arg)
    try:
        time_list = arg.split(',')
        for i in range(len(time_list)):
            print (str(time_list[i]))
            check_valid_time(parser,str(time_list[i]))
    except:
        parser.error("list is invalid input format!")
    return arg
```